# Selecting items in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

My goal is to first select the first 3 items in the dictionary below. I would also like to select items with values greater than 1.

```
dic=Counter({'school': 4, 'boy': 3, 'old': 3, 'the': 1})

My attempt:
1.>>> {x:x for x in dic if x[1]>1}
{'boy': 'boy', 'the': 'the', 'old': 'old', 'school': 'school'}


2.>>>dic[:3]
TypeError: unhashable type

Desired output: Counter({'school': 4, 'boy': 3, 'old': 3})
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: A dictionary has no "first x values", they are unordered. Did you mean the three `most_common` values in the Counter?

Comment: yea, the three most_common. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For items with count greater than one:

```
>>> [x for x in dic if dic[x] > 1]
['boy', 'school', 'old']
```

For the three [most common](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) items:

```
>>> [x for x, freq in dic.most_common(3)]
['school', 'boy', 'old']
```

To get dictionaries:

```
>>> {x: freq for x,freq in dic.items() if freq > 1}
{'boy': 3, 'school': 4, 'old': 3}
>>> {x: freq for x,freq in dic.most_common(3)}
{'boy': 3, 'school': 4, 'old': 3}
```

Note: Those are ordinary dictionaries. Use `Counter(result)` to turn them back into `Counter`s. Alternatively to the dictionary comprehension you can also use the builtin `dict` function to turn a list of tuples into a dictionary, and then make a `Counter` from that.

```
>>> Counter(dict(dic.most_common(3)))
Counter({'school': 4, 'boy': 3, 'old': 3})
```

Comment: perhaps you didn't get me or i didn't explain my question clearly enough. I would like my answer to be in dictionary format, both keys and values included.

Comment: this is close but not exactly in a dictionary format:                       `>>> dic.most_common(3)
[('school', 4), ('boy', 3), ('old', 3)]`